# Yandex tank. Задать rps через консоль

Tags: яндекс-танк

Как задать конфигурацию для step через консоль?
В идеале хочется как параметр передавать `$maxRps`.
Чтобы он затем подставлялся в *site.yaml*

`step(5, 25, 5, ${maxRps})`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [опцию -o](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#command-line-options)

```
 yandex-tank -c test.yaml -o "phantom.load_profile.load_type=rps" -o "phantom.load_profile.schedule=step(5,${maxRPS},5,1m)"
```

Только внимательней прочтите [описание step-а](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=step#tutorials), максимальный рпс - это второй параметр, последним параметром задается длительность ступеньки.